# sed - replace second octet on an IP address

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I would like to replace the second octet on an IP address using sed:

Example:

> 10.**110**.30.11
>
> 10.**133**.30.11

What is the easiest way to perform this task?

Thank you

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/\.[0-9]\+\./.133./' file
```

Comment: Note that is only works with _GNU_ `sed`. With a (mostly) strictly POSIX-features-only `sed` such as on BSD/macOS, you need `sed 's/\.[0-9]\{1,\}\./.133./'`

Answer (score 3):

An attempt in pure `bash`, apart from wonderful `awk` and `sed` answers from above.

```
 $ IFS="." read -r octet1 _ octet3 octet4 <<<"10.110.30.11"
 $ octet2=133
 $ printf "%s.%s.%s.%s\n" "$octet1" "$octet2" "$octet3" "$octet4"
 10.133.30.11
```

Answer (score 1):

I think awk can do it a bit easier, if your input is column based.

```
awk -F'.' -v OFS="." '$2=133'
```

with your example:

```
$ echo "10.110.30.11" | awk -F'.' -v OFS="." '$2=133'
10.133.30.11
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}{$2=133}1' <<< "10.110.30.11"
10.133.30.11
```

*This will change the value of the second octet to 133. Columns are delimited by a literal dot which is defined inside BEGIN block.*

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[0-9]\+/133/2' file
```

Replace the second occurrence of one or more numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
sed -E 's/^([^.]+\.)[^.]+(\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$)/\1133\2/'
```

Note that, matching IP addresses needs some work in Regex, perhaps you should look for specific libraries for your language of choice. For the task in hand, this should do though.

**Example:**

```
% sed -E 's/^([^.]+\.)[^.]+(\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$)/\1133\2/' <<<'10.110.30.11' 
10.133.30.11
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk and `sub`:

```
$ awk 'sub(/\.[0-9]{1,3}\./,".133.")' <(echo 10.110.30.11)
10.133.30.11
```